# What to use for streaming ANY audio to another computer using wifi

Tags: ssh, wifi, audio, raspberry-pi, pulseaudio

Goal: I want my kids to be able to use the raspberry pi (raspbian) hooked up to the TV as a computer terminal to run educational websites and applications (from my desktop via ssh).

Problem: The raspberry pi is Sloooow! Running applications on my Rpi through ssh -X from my desktop is much faster then running applications locally, plus with this method flash works. However getting the audio to stream over to the pi is tricky.

What I've tried: I have setup pulseaudio to basically allow any computer on my network to play any sound it wants to on the pi. I have icons on the Rpi desktop that open ssh connections and run applications from my desktop on the Pi, while forwarding the audio to the Pi's pulse port 4713.

An example script run from an icon:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -XC -c blowfish-cbc,arcfour child@desktop
PULSE_SERVER=Raspberrypi:4713 google-chrome
```

This opens up google-chrome from the desktop on to the Raspberry Pi's display and sends its audio output to the raspberry pi. If my Pi is connected with a network cable this works perfectly! It plays the kid's application sounds on the TV, while letting me hear my applications on the desktop.  Multi user networked audio, it's amazing!

However I read that pulseaudio over wifi is hit or miss depending on your router, and unfortunately it is a miss for me. It plays from 2 seconds to 200 seconds of audio before it cuts out, depending on how congested the airwaves are, what phase the moon is in etc.

I don't intend to have a cable sprawled across my living room, and I really hoped my wall fishing days were over.  Is there a better alternative for my purposes than pulseaudio that will allow me to send ANY audio from my desktop to the pi over wifi? I briefly looked into dlna, but it seems like it's more for sending media files, instead of raw output. Please let me know if I am wrong.  Also, might there be some settings I can fix in my router to allow pulseaudio to work better?

Comment: X over ssh will be always slow, so much more in limited devices. Google NoMachine.

Comment: Well in this case, X over ssh it runs applications faster than the local versions run.  Because the raspberry pi is so slow, using my desktop to take some of the load is a big help.  But that's not really what the question is about, is it?

Comment: Google NoMachine...

Comment: You are directly using the remote pulseaudio server on the RaspPi. A better setup may be user "proper" audio streaming via [RTP](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index7h2) with `module-rtp-send` for a "sink to RaspPi" on your desktop and `module-rtp-receive` on the RaspPi. That way, if the stream interrupts, it can pickup again after the interrupt. It's still hit-or-miss over wifi, especially if you are forwarding X as well. Both need quite a bit of bandwidth together.

Comment: You can script all this using `pacmd`, and use `pavucontrol` to control it with a GUI.